# How can I convert a binary value to text or ascii in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, byte

How can I convert binaries to text or ascii in python 3 without any import of libraries?
For example I have this stored in a variable

```
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000010101000100100001000101001000000101001101000011010000010101001001001100010001010101010000100000010100000100100101001101010100000100010101010010010011100100010101001100000011010000101000001101000010100100001101001000010000010101000001010100010001010101001000100000010010010010000001010000010000010101001001001001010100110011101000100000010100110100010101010000010101000100010101001101010000100100010101010010001011000010000000110001001101110011100100110010
```

Comment: And what would be the expected output for that binary value?

Comment: when you convert it is a title of a book

Comment: So it is. Is this a `bytes()` value or a `str()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chop up the input value into chunks of 8 'bits' and use `int()` to convert it to an integer, then `chr()` to convert it to a character:

```
for i in range(0, len(inputstring), 8):
    print(chr(int(inputstring[i:i + 8], 2)), end='')
```

would do it.

Demo:

```
>>> inputstring = b'0000000000000000000000000000000000000000010101000100100001000101001000000101001101000011010000010101001001001100010001010101010000100000010100000100100101001101010100000100010101010010010011100100010101001100000011010000101000001101000010100100001101001000010000010101000001010100010001010101001000100000010010010010000001010000010000010101001001001001010100110011101000100000010100110100010101010000010101000100010101001101010000100100010101010010001011000010000000110001001101110011100100110010'
>>> for i in range(0, len(inputstring), 8):
...     print(chr(int(inputstring[i:i + 8], 2)), end='')
... 
THE SCARLET PIMPERNEL

CHAPTER I PARIS: SEPTEMBER, 1792>>>
```

Comment: when i am trying to access inputstring which is inside a while loop i cannot access it outside the while loop. do you know how i can access it after it finishes from while?

Comment: @user3238361: Sorry, I have *no* idea what you are talking about. You'll need to show code for that to make sense. That won't work in a comment here; perhaps you need to ask a new question for that.